# Execute SSIS Package result failure DTSError is the executable is not specified

Tags: c#, sql, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I am using C# to execute a package on a remote server. I am able to successfully execute the package from my staging environment but when i push this code to production I am getting the following DTSError "The executable is not specified.\r\n"

The file locations have not changed and again the package executes from my staging environment.  I do not understand why this works in one environment and not the other when they are essentially calling the same SSIS package.  Can anyone help me figure out why this error is being thrown?  I added my c# code below:

```
        protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            string pkgLocation;
            Package pkg;
            Application app;
            DTSExecResult pkgResults;

            pkgLocation = @"\\Someserver\C$\Some_Folder_\Another_folder\Somepackage.dtsx";
          
            app = new Application();
            pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, null);
            pkgResults = pkg.Execute();

            Console.WriteLine(pkgResults.ToString());
            //Console.ReadKey();

            foreach ( Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsError DtsError in pkg.Errors)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(DtsError.Description);
                this.LblDetailResult.Text = DtsError.Description;


            }
```

Comment: Does production have the integration services runtime installed? Services.msc -> SQL Server Integration Services Service (with possibly a version number appended)

Comment: @billinkc Yes. "SQL Server Integration services 13.0"

Comment: Does the package have an Execute Task in it and if so, verify the target executable is available at the same location (or use Expressions to point to the correct path)

Comment: Yes, the package executes a .BAT file.  The path is correct.  I verified all the files are there and permissions are correct.

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue by confirming the DTExec.exe file was missing from the Microsoft SQL Server/140/DTS/Binn folder.  I reinstalled Microsoft SQL Server SSIS and restarted the server.  Confirmed the DTExec.exe file was now present and the application/package now is running as it should.